# Android - List wifi access points

Tags: android, wifi

I want to get list of wifi access points.Thank you very much.My code is below

```
public static void backupWifi(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        String id = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
        int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        String MAC = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
        String SSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        int idnw = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();


            Log.v("ID", id);
            Log.v("IP", String.valueOf(ip));
            Log.v("MAC", MAC);
            Log.v("SSID", SSID);
            Log.v("idnw", String.valueOf(idnw));
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a **BroadcastReceiver** to listen for Wifi scan results:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) {
            List<ScanResult> mScanResults = wifi.getScanResults();
            // add your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

In **onCreate()** you would assign **mWifiManager** and initiate a scan:

```
mWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
mWifiManager.startScan();
```

This code which handles your scan results would run every time a new scan result is available, updating the result.

Comment: Be aware with intent action checking, it should be better  change  to .equals instead ==. Should looks like WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())

Comment: It is safer to use Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
Over == and .equals

Answer (score 2):

First get a list of available wifi points-

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<ScanResult> apList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

apList - is the list of all available wifi points in the most recent scan.

You can set this apList to a ListView.
NB:- this method returns only the recently scanned wifi points

Comment: dont forget to add these permissions in your manifest file.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>